# What is the energy of a body that rotates in an unfixed radius?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

I have a body $m$ that is in a track that limits it's movment only to the radial axis. He is connected to a spring and that track is rotating around the same axis as shown here : [image]

I wonder what is the energy of this system ? Everything is massless except the mass mentoined.
The spring has potential energy of $\frac{kx}{2}$ and what energy does the mass has ? In similar questions I saw in energy calculations usually the energy that gets in the equation is in the radial path $\frac{mv^{2}}{2}$  but what about the speed of the mass in the tangential axis $\frac{Iw^{2}}{2}$?

Answer (score 0):

If you track the particle with polar coordinates you will find the velocity to be $$ \vec{v} =  \pmatrix{ \dot{r} & r \omega }$$

This makes the kinetic energy $$ K = \frac{1}{2} m \| \vec{v} \|^2  = \frac{1}{2} m \left( \dot{r}^2 + r^2 \omega^2 \right) $$

<sub>Were $\dot{r}$ is the speed in the radial direction and $\omega$ the rotational speed</sub>

PS. A point mass does not have a mass moment of inertia.